# как при автоматической авторизации на сайте с помощью библиотеки requests подтвердить вход

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Вопрос следующий: у меня есть код на питоне, который должен заходить на сайт и в форме авторизации вводить логин и пароль.Это у меня получилось, скрипт удачно ввел данные, но осталось как то нажать на кнопку "Вход" Как это можно сделать, или какие есть обходные пути? Имитировать нажатие кнопки можно в библиотеке selenim, но я не могу использовать эту библиотеку, потому что чтобы с помощью selenium ввести логин и пароль в нужные места, нужно знать id из htlm, но он с каждый раз новый, и парсить этот id перед использованием не получается, т.к при попытке спарсить id, он шифруется. В общем нужно как то "подтвердить" введенные данные(например когда мы хотим войти куда нибудь, мы пишем логин, пароль, а потом нажимаем кнопку ВОЙТИ) Вот мой код, который может просто ввести данные на сайт

```
import requests

datas = {
 'auth':'def',
 'Password':'def', 
 '_processLogin':'True'
}
login = 'asasasasasasasa'
passwd = 'zxcvbnm'
datas['auth']  = login
datas['Password'] = passwd

url = 'здесь какая нибуль url'
s = requests.Session()
loging = s.post(url, data = datas)
print(loging)
f = open('result.txt','w+')
f.write(loging.text)
f.close()
```

Comment: на какой сайт делаете авторизацию??

Comment: @Jack_oS 7 да по сути без разницы, но я нашел несколько сайтов с похожей структурой, где id меняется каждый раз при обновлении страницы к примеру id 
 = _xfUid-1-1619109310 А сайт например https://yougame.biz/login

Comment: по сути, содержанию и устройству все сайты - разные ;) вам нужно найти (в панели разработчика) куда и в каком виде отправляется логин-пароль сделать то же срадствами requests

Comment: тот, что вы привели в пример, ожидает такого набора в POST запросе: login: my_name
password: my_pass
g-recaptcha-response: 03AGdBq259-Qm-a4rq3tdJ2nD-8Hc3CkJB0NfEN8znlHTVYaa55sWZvl1sJ3Yyb_oKjNYdsVbj74DWPeFRnYVt8sqnmSnPlrRIr6aY9Rs-8LNkASYYLh80uW20ukJX8WH0PWzniLm_2PMtxm4e4e7xjLyBL4KkbF0Q1RT3fCDzcK0Y2KCZHUUrBwg0q78mgafM4f6Yr1RdZSufsGnihubHsOg8lwD-L_qBJz1o4o6FJ8IWseAUdbFCgsQIxWAk1lC9ZMa6hiU78ZgniNDp8JhjDlzYeHjtneAq3mT3NVWik4hzG3jsnTDYl8_yXHfkntDw6c
remember: 1
_xfRedirect: https://yougame.biz/login
_xfToken: 1619109513,24da74432a5f0b753d5038bdfecbce2a

Comment: @Jack_oS Окей, а какие есть еще варианты? Этот сайт я привел в пример, у меня будет куча других. Может вы знаете того, кто сможет помочь, или может вы сами знаете, как с помошью selenium избежать использования id

Comment: всегда всё парсил с requests...